# How to simplify this geometry?

Tags: modeling

How would you go about simplifying this geometry?
[image]

(Some more info: I wouldn't really be worried about it but at the moment it takes ages to render in cycles and I think it may be because of the amount of verts in the scene?)

Comment: PS. They are many more blocks like this (it's a simple building placement scene), I have considered replacing them with new geometry, but think that may take a while.

Comment: hit X button and select limited dissolve

Comment: It's probably not the vert count that is slowing down a cycles render unless building the BVH is taking a long time

Comment: What's the BVH?

Comment: BVH is how cycles loads all the geometry in the scene when you hit the render button.  If you have a lot of geometry (2million verts +) building the BVH and getting it ready to render will take a bit longer than normal.

Because the way cycles works, mesh density doesn't have too much of an effect on render time. Things like lots of bouncing lights (an interior scene, like from sunlight bouncing off the ground outside, in through the window, then around the room for example)  will slow it down tremendously.

Comment: if you have an 8 million poly scene, building a BVH can take 30 seconds to do, but rendering might be fast in comparison.  If you have a 1000 poly scene, building BVH will be almost instantaneous, but rendering might still be the same time as the 8million poly scene.

Comment: @NeverGiveUp **B**ounding **V**olume **H**ierarchy

Comment: You were right Tim, after experimentation it seems it wasn't the vert count that was slowing cycles so much as the fact that I was using CPU instead of GPU, I also lowered the minimum bounces from 8 to 2 and got rid of the ambient occlusion. The rendering went from 10mins to 30sec after these changes! (Though reducing the vert count did seem to help the viewport display and overall speed still (verts went from 500,000 down to 33,000))

Comment: Oh fantastic, 10 mins to 30seconds is a huge improvement.  By the way, be weary of the cycles "AO render pass."  I've had problems in the past of it increasing render times significantly.     And yeah, you're totally right, vert count will have a huge impact on viewport display no matter what render engine as it will be drawn in blender using openGL (which is not like cycles).   One thing that might help you though, is if under user preferences->system-> (middle column) tick "VBO's" (just below Anisotropic Filtering).  That will help load verts onto the gpu for faster viewport performance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is in fact really easy. Select all the geometry of the object with too many vertices in edit mode by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>. Press <kbd>delete</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd>, depending on which you prefer, and click *limited dissolve*.

[image]

After that, your mesh will look clean.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. 99% of the time decimate gets recommended even when people explicitly ask for a non lossy reduction.